# Destroy object with boolean control

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I found a tap on object in unity tutorial and tried to add some code for destroy object.

My problem is when I try to tap counter decrease and boolean change false.
but if I continue tap on object , enemy still destroy

How can I correct the code?

```
var counter : int =3;
public var destroy = true;
function Update () {
    var hit: RaycastHit;
   var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
   if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)    

    {
       if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 100)) 
      {
           if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "weapon" && destroy==true)

                counter-=1;
                DestroyEnemy();
                Check();
                                  }
        }
    }

function DestroyEnemy() {

 Destroy(GameObject.Find("enemy2(Clone)"));
 Destroy(GameObject.Find("enemy(Clone)"));

}

function Check() {

if (counter <=0)
destroy=false;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably missing the parentheses in your if statement:

```
if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "weapon" && destroy==true)
    counter-=1;
    DestroyEnemy();
    Check();
```

If you run this, only `counter -= 1` will be inside the if statement. `DestroyEnemy()` and `Check()` will be run each time you tap regardless of the `destroy` value. Give parentheses for multi line if statement:

```
if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "weapon" && destroy==true)
{ // this
    counter-=1;
    DestroyEnemy();
    Check();
} // and this
```

Comment: Thank you , just two curly braces . How I could forget them :)